# Create Auto JSONArray with PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have this code in php for creating json array  :

```
<?php
$user = "studentsinfo";


$file = "test_web.txt";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

 $json[$user] = array(
    array(
        "id" => $name,
        "name" => $email

    )
);


echo json_encode($json);

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));

?>
```

in this code i can create json object into json file ( $file = "test_web.txt";) , and it works and the output file is something like :

```
{"studentsinfo":[{"id":"vzxvx","name":"xzvx"}]}
```

but i want some php code or js code that auto give me something like this :

```
{"studentsinfo":[{"id":"1","name":"name1"},{"id":"2","name":"name2"} , ... {"id":"n","name":"namen"}]}
```

is there anyone could give me a favour and help me ?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
$user ='user';
$users =[
  ['id'=>1, 'name'=>'nm1'],
  ['id'=>2, 'name'=>'nm2'],
  ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'nm3']
];

foreach($users as $v){
  $json[$user][]=['id'=>$v['id'], 'name'=>$v['name']];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```